# What's the difference between == and .equals in Scala?

Tags: scala, equality, scala-java-interop

What is the difference between `==` and `.equals()` in Scala, and when to use which?

Is the implementation same as in Java?

EDIT: The related question talks about specific cases of `AnyVal`. The more general case is `Any`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why == operator and equals() behave differently for values of AnyVal in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479333/why-operator-and-equals-behave-differently-for-values-of-anyval-in-scala)

Comment: @Ben I think that other question should be marked as duplicate considering the date asked. Also, I feel the two questions are different.

Comment: There is a [scaladoc in `scala.Equals`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/Equals.scala#L21) which points to [Programming in Scala, Chapter 28, Object Equality](https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/object-equality.html).

Answer (score 225, accepted):

You normally use `==`, it routes to `equals`, except that it treats `null`s properly. Reference equality (rarely used) is `eq`.

Comment: Does it also apply when using Java libraries?

Comment: It does. For instance new java.util.ArrayList[Int]() == new java.util.ArrayList[Int](), as equals on ArrayList is content equality.

Comment: There is also some strange behavior around Int and Long and == versus .equals(). The same number as Int and as Long return true for == but false for equals. So == does not always route to equals.

Comment: More interestingly, Both `3 == BigInt(3)` and `BigInt(3) == 3` are true. But, `3.equals(BigInt(3))` is false, whereas `BigInt(3).equals(3)` is true. Therefore, prefer using `==`. Avoid using `equals()` in scala. I think `==` does implicit conversion well, but `equals()` does not.

Comment: So why `new java.lang.Integer(1) == new java.lang.Double(1.0)` is true while `new java.lang.Integer(1) equals new java.lang.Double(1.0)` is false?

Comment: This answer is probably fine for most people, most of the time, but it is incomplete. `==` and `equals` differ in other, more subtle ways. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35226271/877069).

Answer (score 39):

### TL;DR

- Override `equals` method to compare content of each instance. This is the same `equals` method used in Java
- Use `==` operator to compare, without worrying about `null` references
- Use `eq` method to check if both arguments are **EXACTLY** the same reference. Recommended not to use unless you understand how this works and often `equals` will work for what you need instead. And make sure to only use this with `AnyRef` arguments, not just `Any`

NOTE: On the case of `equals`, just as in Java, it may not return the same result if you switch the arguments eg `1.equals(BigInt(1))` will return `false` where the inverse will return `true`. This is because of each implementation checking only specific types. Primitive numbers dont check if the second argument is of `Number` nor `BigInt` types but only of other primitive types

### Details

The `AnyRef.equals(Any)` method is the one overridden by subclasses. A method from the Java Specification that has come over to Scala too. If used on an unboxed instance, it is boxed to call this (though hidden in Scala; more obvious in Java with `int`->`Integer`). The default implementation merely compares references (as in Java)

The `Any.==(Any)` method compares two objects and allows either argument to be null (as if calling a static method with two instances). It compares if both are `null`, then it calls the `equals(Any)` method on boxed instance.

The `AnyRef.eq(AnyRef)` method compares **only** references, that is where the instance is located in memory. There is no implicit boxing for this method.

### Examples

- `1 equals 2` will return `false`, as it redirects to `Integer.equals(...)`
- `1 == 2` will return `false`, as it redirects to `Integer.equals(...)`
- `1 eq 2` will not compile, as it requires both arguments to be of type `AnyRef`
- `new ArrayList() equals new ArrayList()` will return `true`, as it checks the content
- `new ArrayList() == new ArrayList()` will return `true`, as it redirects to `equals(...)`
- `new ArrayList() eq new ArrayList()` will return `false`, as both arguments are different instances
- `foo equals foo` will return `true`, unless `foo` is `null`, then will throw a `NullPointerException`
- `foo == foo` will return `true`, even if `foo` is `null`
- `foo eq foo` will return `true`, since both arguments link to the same reference

Comment: Can you also explain === in scala?

Answer (score 38):

`==` is a final method, and calls `.equals`, which is not final.

This is radically different than Java, where `==` is an operator rather than a method and strictly compares reference equality for objects.

Answer (score 9):

There is an interesting difference between `==` and `equals` for `Float` and `Double` types: They treat `NaN` differently:

```
scala> Double.NaN == Double.NaN
res3: Boolean = false

scala> Double.NaN equals Double.NaN
res4: Boolean = true
```

*Edit:* As was pointed out in a comment - "this also happens in Java" - depends on what exactly *this* is:

```
public static void main(final String... args) {
    final double unboxedNaN = Double.NaN;
    final Double boxedNaN = Double.valueOf(Double.NaN);

    System.out.println(unboxedNaN == unboxedNaN);
    System.out.println(boxedNaN == boxedNaN);
    System.out.println(boxedNaN.equals(boxedNaN));
}
```

This will print

```
false
true
true
```

So, the `unboxedNan` yields `false` when compared for equality because this is how IEEE floating point numbers define it and this should really happen in every programming language (although it somehow messes with the notion of identity).

The boxed NaN yields true for the comparison using `==` in Java as we are comparing object references.

I do not have an explanation for the `equals` case, IMHO it really should behave the same as `==` on unboxed double values, but it does not.

Translated to Scala the matter is a little more complicated as Scala has unified primitive and object types into `Any` and translates into the primitive double and the boxed Double as needed. Thus the scala `==` apparently boils down to a comparison of primitive `NaN` values but `equals` uses the one defined on boxed Double values (there is a lot of implicit conversion magic going on and there is stuff pimped onto doubles by `RichDouble`).

If you really need to find out if something is actually `NaN` use `isNaN`:

- Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#isNaN(double)
- Scala: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.Double@isNaN():Boolean

Comment: and this also happens in Java!

Comment: See also `0.0 equals -0.0` vs. `0.0 == -0.0`.

Answer (score 5):

In Scala **==** first check for **Null** values and then calls **equals** method on first object