# Why == operator and equals() behave differently for values of AnyVal in Scala

Tags: scala, equals, equality, primitive

In the scaladoc of `scala.Any`, the operator `==` (or, method `==`) is explained:

> The expression `x == that` is equivalent to `if (x eq null) that eq null else x.equals(that)`
>   http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Any

For objects of subclasses of `AnyRef`, I can understand it easily, and I didn't see any strange things.

However, for values of `AnyVal`, (I mean `Int`, `Double`, `Long`, and so on,) the above definition is somewhat tricky (`1 eq null`? This does not compile if we do not convert `1` to java.lang.Integer). Also, `==` and `equals()` behave differently.

I'll give some examples.

```
scala> 1 == 1
res0: Boolean = true

scala> 1 == 1.0
res1: Boolean = true

scala> 1 == 1.2
res2: Boolean = false

scala> 2 == BigInt(2)
res3: Boolean = true

scala> 2.0 == BigInt(2)
res4: Boolean = true

scala> 2 == BigInt(3)
res5: Boolean = false
```

So far, nothing is strange. But if we do the same things with `equals()` methods,

```
scala> 1 equals 1
res7: Boolean = true

scala> 1 equals 1.0
res8: Boolean = false

scala> 1 equals 1.2
res9: Boolean = false

scala> 2 equals BigInt(2)
res10: Boolean = false

scala> 2.0 equals BigInt(2)
res11: Boolean = false

scala> 2 equals BigInt(3)
res12: Boolean = false
```

So if the types are different, equals() always returns false, whereas == tests if they represent the same value if they are converted to the same type.

In the case of subclass of `AnyRef`, methods `==` and `equals()` return the same.

```
scala> BigInt(2) == 2
res25: Boolean = true

scala> BigInt(2) == 2.0
res26: Boolean = true

scala> BigInt(3) == 2
res27: Boolean = false

scala> BigInt(2) equals 2
res28: Boolean = true

scala> BigInt(2) equals 2.0
res29: Boolean = true

scala> BigInt(3) equals 2
res30: Boolean = false
```

So, why methods `==` and `equals()` are diffrent for `AnyVal`?

I'm using Scala version 2.10.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_25).

**EDIT 1**
I saw that == cannot be overriden directly, as it is defined as a final method in class Any according to [Programming in Scala, 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0981531644).

**EDIT 2**
Although there is an answer, my question remains. I will leave this question open.

What correspond to `scala.Int` and `scala.Long` in Java are Java's primitive types `int` and `long`.
In Java, `java.lang.Integer` and `java.lang.Long` are classes, so their variables are references, which can have `null`.
That means, they are like `AnyRef` in Scala. Not `AnyVal`.
Scala's `AnyVal` - `scala.Int` and `scala.Long` cannot have `null` values, neither can Java's `int` and `long`.
Also, `java.lang.Integer`'s `==` in Java is for reference equality (same as `eq` in Scala).
What you get using `java.lang.Integer` in Scala REPL will be quite different from what you get with it in pure Java Project with .java source file in this respect.

However, what I could get from using classes of primitive types in Java was: (THIS IS JAVA)

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(new java.lang.Integer(1).equals(1)));
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(new java.lang.Integer(1).equals(1L)));
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(new java.lang.Integer(1).equals(1.0)));
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(new java.lang.Integer(1).equals(new java.lang.Integer(1))));
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(new java.lang.Integer(1).equals(new java.lang.Long(1))));
    }
}
```

output:

```
true
false
false
true
false
```

Yes, they behave similar to scala AnyVal's `equals()`. But, then, why does this happen?

Does Scala's `AnyVal`'s `==` correspond to `==` of Java's primitive type
and does Scala's AnyVal's `equals()` correspond to `equals()` of Java's class types?
What about equality tests with BigInt? There is no corresponding primitive type in Java.
The question remains...

**EDIT 3**
I could find some information from scaladoc. (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Int)
The *Implicit information* from the item of *Shadowed Implicit Value Members*,
I could find `==` was overloaded for `Char`, `Short`, `Float`, and ...,
and `==` will call implicit conversions `int2double`, `int2float`, or `int2long`.
Whereas `equals()` is only defined for `Any`, and it will call implicit conversion `int2Integer`.
That is, `Int.equals()` will be the same as `java.lang.Integer.equals()`.

One question remains:
Why `==` of `AnyVal` is overloaded, and `equals()` of `AnyVal` is not overloaded?

Comment: I am sorry but I am confused after the whole post. Can you please specify in the end of what is the exact question?

Comment: @Jatin The method `==` and `equals()` are the same in `AnyRef` values in Scala. I think they should be the same for `AnyVal` values, too. In fact, they are different. However, I couldn't find anything about this while I was studying Scala. So, why `==` and `equals()` are not the same for `AnyVal`? Is there some specification about this?

Comment: @Naetmul, what about this output: `println(Double.NaN == Double.NaN)
   println(Double.NaN equals Double.NaN)', i was expectiong true and true but output is false true, don't understand it, any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The relevant discussions are the descriptive

[spec for == from 2010](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/and-equals-td2261488.html)

and the speculative

[Rethinking equality from 2011](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-internals/MhIR30mYt-M/MHD0VHhMqoQJ)

FWIW, the spec calls out equality for numeric value types [in 12.2](https://github.com/scala/scala-dist/blob/master/documentation/src/reference/ReferencePart.tex#L7788).

Or, [in HTML](http://iainmcgin.github.io/scala-ref-markdown/ScalaReference-mathml.html#numeric-value-types). (Quote at bottom, below.)

In his "pidgin spec-ese" of 2010, Paul Phillips puts it this way:

> comparing two primitives (boxed or unboxed) with == should always give
>   the result you would have gotten by comparing those values as unboxed
>   primitives.  When you call equals directly, you are skipping all that
>   softening logic and instead treated to java's theory that two boxed
>   values of different types are always unequal.

The spec doesn't speak of boxed primitives, aside from a passing reference in 12.5 to the conversions provided by `Predef`.  You're not generally meant to be aware of when a primitive is stored in its "boxed" form, unless of course you need to for performance reasons.

So, for example, these values are silently unboxed and promoted for you:

```
scala> val ds = List(7.0)
ds: List[Double] = List(7.0)

scala> val is = List(7)
is: List[Int] = List(7)

scala> ds(0) == is(0)
res24: Boolean = true

scala> :javap -
  Size 1181 bytes
  MD5 checksum ca732fd4aabb301f3ffe0e466164ed50
  Compiled from "<console>"
[snip]
     9: getstatic     #26                 // Field .MODULE$:L;
    12: invokevirtual #30                 // Method .ds:()Lscala/collection/immutable/List;
    15: iconst_0      
    16: invokevirtual #36                 // Method scala/collection/immutable/List.apply:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;
    19: invokestatic  #42                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.unboxToDouble:(Ljava/lang/Object;)D
    22: getstatic     #47                 // Field .MODULE$:L;
    25: invokevirtual #50                 // Method .is:()Lscala/collection/immutable/List;
    28: iconst_0      
    29: invokevirtual #36                 // Method scala/collection/immutable/List.apply:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;
    32: invokestatic  #54                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt:(Ljava/lang/Object;)I
    35: i2d           
    36: dcmpl
```

I'm kind of surprised that you note

```
2.0 == BigInt(2)  // So far, nothing is strange.
```

To me, that's slightly magical. It calls into `BoxesRunTime.equals` as described by Paul Phillips.

```
     9: ldc2_w        #22                 // double 2.0d
    12: invokestatic  #29                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToDouble:(D)Ljava/lang/Double;
    15: getstatic     #34                 // Field scala/package$.MODULE$:Lscala/package$;
    18: invokevirtual #38                 // Method scala/package$.BigInt:()Lscala/math/BigInt$;
    21: iconst_2      
    22: invokevirtual #44                 // Method scala/math/BigInt$.apply:(I)Lscala/math/BigInt;
    25: invokestatic  #48                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
```

Here is the spec, for reference, which in this form basically just promises to do the right thing:

> The equals method tests whether the argument is a numeric value type.
>   If this is true, it will perform the == operation which is appropriate
>   for that type. That is, the equals method of a numeric value type can
>   be thought of being defined as follows:

```
def equals(other: Any): Boolean = other match {
  case that: Byte   => this == that
  case that: Short  => this == that
  case that: Char   => this == that
  case that: Int    => this == that
  case that: Long   => this == that
  case that: Float  => this == that
  case that: Double => this == that
  case _ => false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I expect this was done because of auto-boxing and a desire to stay consistent with expectations held over from Java, and maths in generel (1 = 1.0 = 1 (represented as a long) etc.). For example, running comparisons between Scala numeric types and Java numeric types:

```
scala> val foo: Long = 3L
foo: Long = 3

scala> val bar: Int = 3
bar: Int = 3

scala> foo == bar
res0: Boolean = true

scala> foo.equals(bar)
res1: Boolean = false
```

Compared with:

```
scala> val jfoo = new java.lang.Long(3L)
jfoo: Long = 3

scala> val jbar = new java.lang.Integer(3)
jbar: Integer = 3

scala> jfoo == jbar
res2: Boolean = true

scala> jfoo.equals(jbar)
res3: Boolean = false
```

Comment: In the real Java, both `new java.lang.Long(3L)` and `new java.lang.Integer(3)` are references. In addition, `java.lang.Long` cannot be cast to `java.lang.Integer`; it will throw `java.lang.ClassCastException`. If you compare these references before converted to same type, it will not even compile: It will generate Compilation error: "incomparable types: java.lang.Integer and java.lang.Long" I think `java.lang.Long` will be automatically converted into `scala.Long`, and `java.lang.Integer` will be automatically converted into `scala.Int`. The above code will not run in the pure Java.