# Why is Scala's == different in case of Int?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

Isn't it supposed to call equals behind the scene?

```
scala> 1 equals 1l
res2: Boolean = false

scala> 1 == 1l
res3: Boolean = true
```

Comment: No, it is supposed to do the right thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @MichaelLang suggests, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18585096/1668144) answer can help you, concretely:

> comparing two primitives (boxed or unboxed) with == should always give
>   the result you would have gotten by comparing those values as unboxed
>   primitives. When you call equals directly, you are skipping all that
>   softening logic and instead treated to java's theory that two boxed
>   values of different types are always unequal.

If you analyze the bytecode:

**1 == 1l** produces

```
         0: aload_0       
         1: invokespecial #19                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: aload_0       
         5: putstatic     #21                 // Field MODULE$:L;
         8: aload_0       
         9: iconst_1      
        10: putfield      #17                 // Field res0:Z
        13: return
```

directly compares the values of both primitive 1's, but if you examine:

**1 equals 1l** then

```
     0: aload_0       
     1: invokespecial #19                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
     4: aload_0       
     5: putstatic     #21                 // Field MODULE$:L;
     8: aload_0       
     9: iconst_1      
    10: invokestatic  #27                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
    13: lconst_1      
    14: invokestatic  #31                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToLong:(J)Ljava/lang/Long;
    17: invokevirtual #35                 // Method java/lang/Object.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    20: putfield      #17                 // Field res0:Z
    23: return
```

Where you can see that is boxing 1l primitive into a Long object and then performing the equals.

Answer (score 4):

From [Programming in Scala 2nd Edition](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_2ed), chapter 11

> 1 The only cases where
>   == is does not directly call equals is for Java’s boxed numeric classes such as Integer or Long . In Java, a new Integer(1) does not
>   equal a new Long(1) even though for primitive values 1 == 1L . Since
>   Scala is a more regular language than Java it was necessary correct
>   this discrepancy by special-casing the == method for these classes.
>   Likewise, the ## method provides a Scala version of hashing that is
>   the same as Java’s hashCode , except for boxed numeric types, where it
>   works consistently with == . For in- stance new Integer(1) and new
>   Long(1) hash the same with ## even though their Java hashCode s are
>   different.