# Scala comparison error

Tags: scala, comparison

I am trying to compare an item from a List of type Strings to an integer. I tried doing this but I get an error saying that:

```
'value < is not a member of List[Int]'
```

The line of code that compares is something similar to this:

```
if(csvList.map(x => x(0).toInt) < someInteger)
```

Besides the point of why this happens, I wondered why I didn't get an error
when I used a different type of comparison, such as  ' == '.

So if I run the line:

```
if( csvList.map(x => x(0).toInt) == someInteger)
```

I don't get an error. Why is that?

Comment: Everything has member `equals`. People don't like that. It's a Java thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with some introductions before answering the questions
Using the REPL you can understand a bit more what you are doing

```
scala> List("1", "2", "3", "33").map(x => x(0).toInt)
res1: List[Int] = List(49, 50, 51, 51)
```

The map function is used to transform every element, so x inside the map will be "1" the first time, "2" the second, and so on.

When you are using x(0) you are accessing the first character in the String.

```
scala> "Hello"(0)
res2: Char = H
```

As you see the type after you have mapped your strings is a List of Int. And you can compare that with an Int, but it will never be equals.

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3) == 5
res0: Boolean = false
```

This is very much like in Java when you try

```
"Hello".equals(new Integer(1));
```

If you want to know more about the reasons behind the equality problem you can check out [Why has Scala no type-safe equals method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742527/why-has-scala-no-type-safe-equals-method)

Last but not least, you get an error when using less than because there is no less than in the List class.

**Extra:** 
If you want to know if the second element in the list is smaller than 2 you can do

```
scala> val data = List("1", "10", "20")
data: List[String] = List(1, 10, 20)
scala> 5 < data(1).toInt
res2: Boolean = true
```

Although it is a bit strange, maybe you should transform the list of string is something a bit more typed like a case class and then do your business logic with a more clear data model.

Comment: That's great info @JonasAnso! however, I am trying to compare one specific element in the list. For exmaple if someInterger < second element on list..

Comment: I tried lift but that gives me the same error. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: ok. So what's different about the 'extra'? It looks the same as before to me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to 
[Why == operator and equals() behave differently for values of AnyVal in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479333/why-operator-and-equals-behave-differently-for-values-of-anyval-in-scala)

Every class support operator ==, but may not support <,> these operators.

in your code

```
csvList.map(x => x(0).toInt)
```

it returns a *List<int>*, and application use it to compare with a int, 
so it may process a implicit type conversion. Even the compiler doesn't report it as a error. Generally, it's not good to compare value with different types.

Answer (score 1):

`csvList.map(x => x(0).toInt)` converts the entire `csvList` to a `List[Int]` and then tries to apply the operator `<` to `List[Int]` and `someInteger` which does not exist. This is essentially what the error message is saying.

There is no error for `==` since this operator exists for `List` though `List[T] == Int` will always return false.

Perhaps what you are trying to do is compare each item of the `List` to an `Int`. If that is the case, something like this would do:

```
scala> List("1","2","3").map(x => x.toInt < 2)
res18: List[Boolean] = List(true, false, false)
```

Answer (score 1):

The piece of code `csvList.map(x => x(0).toInt)` actually returns a `List[Int]`, that is not comparable with a integer (not sure what it would mean to say that `List(1,2) < 3`).
If you want to compare each element of the list to your number, making sure they are all inferior to it, you would actually write `if(csvList.map(x => x.toInt).forall { _ < someInteger })`