# Is equals() method of scala case classes always working properly?

Tags: string, scala, equals, case-class

I have a case class which has 2 parameters of type `Long` and `String`. I was assuming that auto generated `equals()` method would work as desired (meaning it really checks that the `(Long, String)` pair is the same), but apparently it doesn't always do that. It seems like Scala generates equals method in which it checks equality of each member with `==` operator. Is this correct?

Comment: Could you give an example of the unexpected observed behavior and tell which behavior you expected instead?

Comment: Seems like that behavior is not because of equals(). In case you're interested, I'm using apache Spark and there is a method called reduceByKey. This key in my case is a case class, and it produced some repeated values. That's why I was thinking that maybe equals doesn't work as I expected, but seems like there is some other issue.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Evidence of a problem with  just a Long and a String parameter would have been a bit alarming :-)

Answer (score 3):

In Scala, `equals` and `==` are basically the same thing, except `==` handles `null`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681161/whats-the-difference-between-and-equals-in-scala), or in the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.AnyRef@==%28AnyRef%29):

> The expression `x == that` is equivalent to `if (x eq null) that eq null else x.equals(that)`.

It is recommended to generally use `==`.  Reference equality is checked using `eq` (rare).

For case classes, `equals` is automatically implemented (and therefore so is `==` which routes to `equals`):

```
case class Foo(a: Long, b: String)
val foo1 = Foo(1L, "")
val foo2 = Foo(1L, "")
val foo3 = Foo(2L, "")

foo1 == foo2 //true
foo1.equals(foo2) //true

foo1 == foo3 //false
foo1.equals(foo3) //false
```

From the [docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/case-classes.html):

> For every case class the Scala compiler generates an `equals` method
>   which implements structural equality and a `toString` method.