# What is the difference between ArrayBuffer and Array

Tags: arrays, scala

I'm new to scala/java and I have troubles getting the difference between those two.

By reading the scala [doc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayBuffer.html) I understood that `ArrayBuffer` are made to be interactive (append, insert, prepend, etc).

1) What are the fundamental implementation differences?

2) Is there performance variation between those two?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Both `Array` and `ArrayBuffer` are mutable, which means that you can modify elements at particular indexes: `a(i) = e`

`ArrayBuffer` is resizable, `Array` isn't. If you append an element to an `ArrayBuffer`, it gets larger. If you try to append an element to an `Array`, you get a new array. Therefore to use `Array`s efficiently, you must know its size beforehand.

`Array`s are implemented on JVM level and are the only non-erased generic type. This means that they are the most efficient way to store sequences of objects – no extra memory overhead, and some operations are implemented as single JVM opcodes.

`ArrayBuffer` is implemented by having an `Array` internally, and allocating a new one if needed. Appending is usually fast, unless it hits a limit and resizes the array – but it does it in such a way, that the overall effect is negligible, so don't worry. Prepending is implemented as moving all elements to the right and setting the new one as the 0th element and it's therefore slow. Appending *n* elements in a loop is efficient (*O*(*n*)), prepending them is not (*O*(*n*²)).

`Array`s are specialized for built-in value types (except `Unit`), so `Array[Int]` is going to be much more optimal than `ArrayBuffer[Int]` – the values won't have to be boxed, therefore using less memory and less indirection. Note that the specialization, as always, works only if the type is monomorphic – `Array[T]` will be always boxed.

Comment: Ques: what does Karol mean bt boxed?Great explanation.

Comment: @datmannz Boxing in Scala is mostly the same as in Java, and here's official documentation about Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Answer (score 4):

The one other difference is, Array's element created as on when its declared but Array Buffer's elements not created unless you assign values for the first time.

For example. You can write  `Array1(0)="Stackoverflow"` but not `ArrayBuffer1(0)="Stackoverflow"` for the first time value assignments.

(Array1 = Array variable &  ArrayBuffer1 = ArrayBuffer variable)

Because as we know, Array buffers are re-sizable, so elements created when you insert values at the first time and then you can modify/reassign them at the particular element.

### Array:

Declaring and assigning values to Int Array.

```
val favNums= new Array[Int](20)

for(i<-0 to 19){
favNums(i)=i*2
}
favNums.foreach(println)
```

### ArrayBuffer:

Declaring and assigning values to Int ArrayBuffer.

```
val favNumsArrayBuffer= new ArrayBuffer[Int]
    for(j<-0 to 19){
    favNumsArrayBuffer.insert(j, (j*2))
    //favNumsArrayBuffer++=Array(j*3)
      }
    favNumsArrayBuffer.foreach(println)
```

If you include `favNumsArrayBuffer(j)=j*2` at the first line in the for loop, It doesn't work. But it works fine if you declare it in 2nd or 3rd line of the loop. Because values assigned already at the first line now you can modify by element index.

This simple one-hour video tutorial explains a lot.

https://youtu.be/DzFt0YkZo8M?t=2005

Comment: Insert & remove doesn't works with Array but ArrayBuffer.

Comment: favNumsArrayBuffer.insert(5,0,1,2,3,4)

Answer (score 3):

Use an **Array** if the length of Array is fixed, and an **ArrayBuffer** if the length can vary.

Comment: Why is that if the `:+=` works on `Array`? How does this answer improve on or contribute to the more detailed answer from @KarolS?

Answer (score 1):

Another difference is in term of reference and value equality

```
Array(1,2) == Array(1,2)              // res0: Boolean = false
ArrayBuffer(1, 2) == ArrayBuffer(1,2) // res1: Boolean = true
```

The reason for the difference is `==` [routes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7681243/5205022) to `.equals` where `Array.equals` is implemented using Java's `==` which compares references

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  return (this == obj);
}
```

whilst [`ArrayBuffer.equals`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/fba65cabc6c4a0488415914ecd2848311138b581/src/library/scala/collection/Seq.scala#L41) compares elements contained by `ArrayBuffer`  using `sameElements` method

```
  override def equals(o: scala.Any): Boolean = this.eq(o.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]) || (
    o match {
      case it: Seq[A] => (it eq this) || (it canEqual this) && sameElements(it)
      case _ => false
    }
  )
```

[Similarly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57772551/5205022), `contains` behaves differently

```
Array(Array(1,2)).contains(Array(1,2))                   // res0: Boolean = false
ArrayBuffer(ArrayBuffer(1,2)).contains(ArrayBuffer(1,2)) // res1: Boolean = true
```