# How to use contains method on a 2D array in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array and I want to check whether an array exists inside the 2d array.

I have tried:

```
var arr = Array(Array(2,1), Array(4,3))
var contain = arr.contains(Array(4, 3))
println(contain)
```

This should print **true** but it doesn't work.

Comment: The problem is that `Arrays` use **reference equality** instead of **value equality**. The best would be to do not use `Arrays`. Or you can create your own method that iterates over the matrix, to check if the value exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `ArrayBuffer` instead of `Array`, if you need [mutable collection](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/concrete-mutable-collection-classes.html), like so

```
val arr = ArrayBuffer(ArrayBuffer(2,1), ArrayBuffer(4,3))
val contain = arr.contains(ArrayBuffer(4, 3))
println(contain)
```

which outputs

```
true
```

Also consider question [What is the difference between ArrayBuffer and Array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31213733/5205022)

Comment: But I need mutable data

Answer (score 4):

Method `contains` doesn't work because it uses `equals` to determine equality and for arrays `equals` is using **reference equality**, so it will return true only for two references pointing the same object.

You could use `find` + `sameElements`:

```
var arr = Array(Array(2,1), Array(4,3))
var contain = arr.find(_.sameElements(Array(4, 3))).isDefined
println(contain)
```

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant solution would be the following

```scala
val array = Array(Array(2,1), Array(4,3))
val result = array.exists(_.sameElements(Array(4, 3)))
println(result)
```

**Output**

```scala
true
```