# If Scala's == calls equals, why doesn't this throw an exception?

Tags: scala

```
scala> val x:String = null
x: String = null

scala> x == "Hey"
res0: Boolean = false
```

This should translate to x.equals("Hey")?

Comment: Because `==` is not equal to `equals`, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681161/whats-the-difference-between-and-equals-in-scala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the SLS:

> 6.3 The Null Value
>
> The null value is of type scala.Null, and is thus compatible with every reference type. It denotes a reference value which refers to a special “null” object. This object implements methods in class scala.AnyRef as follows:
>
> • eq(x ) and ==(x ) return true iff the argument x is also the “null” object.
>
> • ne(x ) and !=(x ) return true iff the argument x is not also the “null” object.
>
> • isInstanceOf[T ] always returns false.
>
> • asInstanceOf[T ] returns the default value (see §4.2) of type T .
>
> • ## returns “0”. A reference to any other member of the “null” object causes a NullPointerException to be thrown.