# Comparison in Scala

Tags: scala

What is the difference between `val a=new String("Hello")` and `val a="Hello"`

Example:

```
val a="Hello"
val b="Hello"
a eq b
res:Boolean=True
```

Similarly:

```
val a=new String("Hello")
val b=new string("Hello")
a eq b
res:Bolean=False
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`eq` compares memory references.

String literals are put in a string constants pool, so in the first example they share the same memory reference. This is a behavior that [comes from Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) (`scala.String` is built on top of `java.lang.String`).

In the second example you're allocating two instances at runtime so when you compare them they're are at different memory locations.

This is exactly the same as Java, so you can refer to this answer for more information: [What is the difference between "text" and new String("text")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext)

Now, if you want to compare their values (as opposed to their memory references), you can use `==` (or `equals`) in Scala.

Example:

```
val a = new String("Hello")
val b = new String("Hello")
a eq b // false
a == b // true
a equals b // true
```

This is different than Java, where `==` is an operator that behaves like `eq` in Scala.

Also note that `==` and `equals` are slightly different in the way the deal with `null` values (`==` is generally advised). More on the subject: [Whats the difference between == and .equals in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681161/whats-the-difference-between-and-equals-in-scala)

Comment: "String literals are put in a string constants pool" – can you provide any source for that? I tried to find a reference in the Scala Language Specification, but there is nothing in the section on [`String`](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/01-lexical-syntax.html#string-literals)s. There *is* an explicit reference to pooling in the section on [`Symbol`](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/01-lexical-syntax.html#symbol-literals)s ("The `apply` method of `Symbol`'s companion object caches weak references to `Symbol`s, thus ensuring that identical symbol literals are …

Comment: … equivalent with respect to reference equality."), so the fact that something similar is *not* documented for `String`s seems to be a *deliberate* omission and not a simple oversight, or, in other words, the Scala designers do *not* guarantee `String` pooling the same way they guarantee for `Symbol`s.

Comment: It's not in the Scala Language Specification because it is Java's behavior from [JLS §3.10.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) whose behavior is implemented in [JVM spec 5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html). The term commonly used is string "interning." See my answer below.

Comment: Thanks for the link @ScottShipp. Indeed this is a behavior that comes from Java. Scala Strings are build on top of java.lang.String.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `eq` (and its opposite `ne`) are used for what is called *reference equality.*

The behavior you observed is the result of what's technically known as *string interning* and is the inherited behavior from Java. Scala makes use of java.util.String under the hood. You can observe this in the REPL:

```
scala> val s = "Hello World!"
s: String = Hello World!

scala> s.isInstanceOf[java.lang.String]
res1: Boolean = true
```

[You can see a general explanation of eq, ne, and == here](http://code.scottshipp.com/2016/08/01/scala-equality-java-equality/).

[To learn about JVM string interning see this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning).