# Lists/Tuples of the same value in memory

Tags: scala, memory, data-structures

If I have the following

```
val A = List(1,2,3)
val B = List(1,2,3)
```

will these two variables have the same memory address or not?

Comment: If a `List` is mutable, you can prove this for yourself. Put a different value into A() and then see if B() has changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They will not have the same memory address which can be confirmed using `eq` method which [compares memory references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38971493/5205022) like so

```
A eq B // returns false
```

Comment: Thanks Mario,

I was asked this question in an interview ... but the question was if I have List a (1,2,3) and List b (1,2,3) ... what will happen in memory