# null.==(obj) does not throw null pointer exception in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am new to scala. Please help me to understand below code snippet

```
null.==("goutam") // ---> return false
null.equals("goutam") // ---> throw NullPointerException
```

As per my understanding null is the only instance of Null trait which extends Anyref and == and equals both are functions of AnyRef. so why first statement does not throw but second one does?

Comment: It makes sense that `null.==("goutam")` doesn't throw `NullPointerException`, because this is the same as `null == "goutam"` (just different method call syntax) and you would not expect that to throw an NPE.

Answer (score 7):

> Why first statement does not throw but second one does

Per the language specification (6.3), there are specific methods on `null` which will not cause a `NullReferenceException` to occur if invoked. They're defined as:

> ### 6.3 The Null Value
>
> The `null` value is of type `scala.Null`, and is thus
>   compatible with every reference type. It denotes a reference value
>   which refers to a special “null” object. This object implements
>   methods in class `scala.AnyRef` as follows:
>
> - `eq(x)` and `==(x)` return true iff the argument x is also the "null"
>     object.
> - `ne(x)` and `!=(x)` return true iff the argument x is not also the
>     "null" object.
> - `isInstanceOf[T]` always returns false.
> - `asInstanceOf[T]` returns the default value of type T.
> - `##` returns 0.
>
> A reference to any other member of the "null" object **causes a NullPointerException to be thrown**.

`equals` is defined on `AnyRef` and doesn't handle `null` values as per definition. `eq`, which checks for *reference equality* (that's usually not what you want to do) can be used:

```
scala> null.==("goutam")
res0: Boolean = false

scala> null.eq("goutam")
res1: Boolean = false
```

`==` does handle `null` properly, and that is what you should be using. More on that in [Whats the difference between == and .equals in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681161/whats-the-difference-between-and-equals-in-scala)