# How to compare two objects for equality in Scala?

Tags: scala, object, equality, assertion

I have a very basic equality check between two objects but it fails.

```
package foo
import org.junit.Assert._

object Sandbox extends App{
  class A

  val a = new A
  val b = new A
  assertEquals(a, b)

}
```

My use-case is more complex but I wanted to get my basics right. I get an assertion error when I run the code:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<foo.Sandbox$A@3f86d38b> but was:<foo.Sandbox$A@206d63fd>
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:743)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
. . . .
```

How can I compare two objects for equality?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala, Java and equality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422669/scala-java-and-equality)

Answer (score 5):

1. You can override AnyRef *equals* function (the same way as you would need to override Object.equals in Java)

   ```
   def equals(arg0: Any): Boolean
   ```
2. Or you can make A *case class*, Scala generates correct equals for case classes out of the box.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately java defined an `equals` a `hashCode` and a `toString` method on every object. The default implementation of `equals` is to check referential equality, that is that they check that you are referring to the exact same object. Since you created two different objects, and gave no equals method to `A` they are not equal, since they aren't the same instance.

You can provide `A` with a better `equals` method, but anytime you override `equals` you should override `hashCode` as well to ensure that they two are in agreement. The rules for them being in agreement are:

- if equals returns true, the two objects must return the same hashCode
- if objects have different hashCodes, equals must return false.